# How to cache a layer manually in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-layer

I'm trying to rebuild a docker image, I modified the source code in index.js.

The dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Since I modified the code in index.js the the layer (copy . . ) in the Dockerfile is uncached, so the upcoming layers will also become uncached. Is there any possible way that I can modify the Dockerfile, If the package.json is not modified then I want the RUN npm install layer to be cached.

I'm a beginner in docker I need a suggesion to implement my problem

Comment: Share Your Current Dockerfile also so that anyone can suggest changes to cache the node artifacts of npm.

Comment: `COPY package.json` into your image, then `RUN npm install`, then `COPY` the rest of the application in.  The linked question has several example setups.

Comment: @RaviKyada I added the code I used before, Thank you

Comment: @DavidMaze Thankyou, It worked. Is there any other way of doing it?